# Embedding native widget in Webkit view

Tags: c#, c, user-interface, webkit, gtk

This is something I've been trying to find out if it is possible and how to do it. I would like to be able to embed a Gtk+ control/widget within a Webkit view, integrated as part of the webpage. For instance, I was hoping that it could be possible to integrate a specific control in the middle of a programmatically generated webpage loaded onto a Webkit instance in a Gtk+ application. I'd like to make it a part of the DOM, if possible.

My intent is to use the webview as a basis for some parts of the UI, but there are some specific controls that needed to be the original Gtk+ ones.

When dealing with controls in forms, for instance, one of two things happen, either Webkit-gtk renders them explicitly to look like the Gtk+ controls, or makes use of actual Gtk +controls and embeds them. If the reality is the second case, then it might actually be easy to do it with other controls as well.

I'm developing the application in C# (mono) with GTK#, but I'm also hoping that if it is possible to do it directly in Gtk+, then it might eventually be possible to do in GTK#.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be possible in WebKitGTK 1.x, but since WebKitGTK has become multiprocess, the capability has been removed.

However, you may be in luck, since GTK# uses quite old versions of libraries. I can't tell what version of WebKitGTK you're using, but if it has the [`create-plugin-widget`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-create-plugin-widget) signal then you should be able to do this.

I've never used this signal before, but I believe it works like this: you put an `<object>` tag into your HTML, and then the signal will be emitted when the webview needs to embed your widget. In the signal handler, you create your widget, and pass it as the return value of the signal handler.

Comment: I was able to catch the signal, but not do anything about it, as it fails to provide correct handler argument type to do so. It is applying System.EventArgs even if I try to use `m_viewWelcome.AddSignalHandler("create-plugin-widget", new GLib.GSignalHandler(onCreatePluginWidget), typeof(GLib.GSignalArgs));`
The error I get is:
`Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.Exception: Unknown type GHashTable`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Broadway](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html). This is the web backend for GTK+, and uses HTML5 to display GTK+ widgets. You may have to use entirely GTK+ in your webpage, but this seems to be the only way to make a webpage containing GTK+ elements.

Comment: That actually defeats the purpose. If I'm only allowed to use Gtk+ in my page, then there's no added value on using it, actually the opposite, as the increased latency and performance degradation from the added processing layers would render it useless. I can see Broadway being useful in some cases but not on this one.

Comment: How deep did you look into it? I should clarify that in my answer, but I didn't look at it in detail, so I can't be sure you can use only GTK+ in the page. I'll clarify that I don't know and see if I can also find more detail.

Comment: Part of my answer was based on yours, but after testing, it proved my assumption that there was no benefit, as a simple interface with one main very simple window and one dialog were slow to a crawl on a i7-6700T with 32GB of RAM and responsiveness was near null.

Comment: It looks like from the link I posted that the webpage must be entirely GTK+. Is there a specific reason you need the GTK+ widgets?

Comment: Gtk+ is definitely a requirement because the project is using GTK# in Mono, but the ability to use Gtk+ widgets inside a webpage under WebKit would make it extremely simpler to develop the whole interface, as it is a very extensive project UI wise. The interface could be developed declaratively, adding only the non HTML native widgets required. An example of such a widget required is GtkSourceView.

Comment: Are you sure there is no HTML widget for source viewing and highlighting? I'm not very knowledgeable about web design, so I'm just throwing out a possibility.

Comment: There are several HTML widgets for source viewing and highlighting, but not of them with the performance or specific feature set that GtkSourceView provides, despite the fact that such a widget is only one example of several that are needed. Even if feature-wise they were available, the objective is being able to quickly prototype interfaces that can easily be manipulated dynamically while still maintaining responsiveness and low memory footprint, something that complex composed HTML widgets are unable to comply with.